# How to make a great R Raster reproducible example

Tags: r, r-raster

When I have to make a reproducible example in R, either to write questions or take examples for specific problems, I usually go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and check the most popular answers. But when working with spatial data with the `raster` package, there are many ways besides the example shown by Roman Luštrik in this popular question. Sometimes structures other than the `stack` such as `brick` or `spatialpixelsdataframe` are needed. Other times it is necessary to create a raster with discrete or continuous data.

So I pose a similar question with a slight variation...

What are your tips? How does one make a great r **RASTER** reproducible example?